# Не отображается Google reCapcha в Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, recaptcha

Возможно кто-то знает - почему не отображается Google reCapcha в  Drupal 7, хотя в админке она есть?

Comment: а как вы ее настроили, и настроили ли вообще?

Comment: Установил модуль, зарегистрировал домен, она работает, то есть, я подключал модуль "Random Capha" то он выводит ее и все работает, если я просто оставляю reCapha то оно не отображает но отправлять тоже не дает, со стилями нет проблем (т.к в рандоме она есть), самое интересное что она не выводится на экран но работает (random не подходит, нужен только один тип проверки но очень надежный хотелось бы что бы это была от google)....